# Create historical data directories with crontab

Tags: cron, command-line-arguments

For this specific project I am collecting data from the internet on an hourly basis and placing it into a directory within a hadoop framework. I need to run specific programs at specific times and crontab is the best way to do this. The problem is I don't know how to create the new files, put them in the proper directories and name them BASED on the time they were made. Crontab takes the commands exactly as they would appear in the command line. Do I have to write a separate program to modify the crontab file so its naming everything properly?

Basically what I want it to do is something like

```
1 * * * * python /location/of/pyfile/stream.py > 
/home/hadoop/project/d2015/"currentmonth"/subfolder/"filenametimestamp".txt
```

Everything in quotes is what needs to change on an hourly/monthly basis.

Comment: This isn't python specific, just create an actual python script that does everything you want, and call that with the cron job. Don't try to put much logic into a cron command itself, I never use them for anything other than launching other scripts or programs. Then you can create the paths etc dynamically in your script, without trying to figure out how to force that into a cron job line.

Comment: As mentioned above, you should create a shell wrapper which get's invoked by the crontab on a periodic basis. You shell wrapper will primarily be responsible for two things: create timestamped directories and executing the python script.